# Why won't this Javascript code execute in Firefox & Chrome?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this set of Javascript code that works fine in IE (any version), but won't work on Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome. Can someone advise me why?

```
function returnData(strCode,strProgramCode,strName)
    {           
        parent.opener.document.all.txtCourseCode[7].value = strCode;      
        parent.opener.document.all.txtProgram[7].value = strProgramCode;                                                
        parent.opener.document.getElementById("txtCourseName8").innerHTML = strName;                

        window.close()
}
```

FYI, this Javascript is embedded into a .aspx page that was written using .NET Framework 1.1.

**Edit** Doesn't work means: none of the lines executed although they were explicitly invoked.

Example: `window.close()` doesn't close the window

Comment: Define does not work. And check for JS errors on the page.

Comment: @RWPH Now that's a LOL-inducing SO username :-D

Comment: I think it simply means that the code won't execute and doesn't necessarily generate any error. Anyway I have edited my question to help you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.all` is an IE-only property, so obviously it won't work in other browsers.

You shouldn't use `document.all` anyway. By the look of things, you're actually wanting:

```
parent.opener.document.getElementsByName('txtCourseCode')[7].value = strCode;
parent.opener.document.getElementsByName('txtProgram')[7].value = strProgramCode;
```

Comment: Thank's this explains the first 3 lines. But the `window.close()` also won't work, what's your opinion?

Comment: `window.close()` is supposed to only work if the window was opened in JavaScript to start with. However there may be complications. Have you checked your error console?

Comment: I am not sure about the complications, will have to check on that. Anyway thx for the enlightenment.